# flutter Exception caught by image resource service Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///

Tags: flutter

hi everyone I have been working on my application and I want to retrieve an images that I save to firebase storage as it is appears to the photo below [image]

and I use this line of code to retrieve the image from the fire storage

```
flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                          background: Image.network(
                              Provider.of<UserModel>(context).bannerImageUrl,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
```

but the error appears to the title facing me and make my simulator like this

[image]

I don't know what is the problem please help;

Comment: most likely `Image.network` accepts `http(s)://` scheme only - not `file://`

Comment: this is the image url https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/insightsoftware-97714.appspot.com/o/Users%2Fprofile%2FtSSy64CPcdM5moiRAcxSmyXx8Fs2%2Fbanner?alt=media&token=0598d020-c7c6-427d-9a8c-73214e2f32a1. it is not a file

Comment: what do you see if you `print(Provider.of<UserModel>(context).bannerImageUrl)`?

Comment: I see this.    Image(image: NetworkImage("", scale: 1.0), frameBuilder: null, loadingBuilder: null, fit: cover, alignment: Alignment.center, this.excludeFromSemantics: false, filterQuality: low)

Comment: `bannerImageUrl` is a `String`, so what value does it have? what you posted above is not a valid url